# How to enable the menu bar and the status bar in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: menu-bar, statusbar

I have just installed 13.04.

However, the global menu when I select the files folder does not show the options like : Edit, View etc.

Is there a way to enable this?

How can I enable the status-bar for the folders? I want to see the number of files in a folder.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! "I want to see the number of files in a folder." That seems to be another question. Please limit each post to one question. You can ask another question for that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has changed in Nautilus (the file browser). Since it no longer uses the menu bar for that, it doesn't show in the panel either. However, there is a button to the right of the toolbar which displays the items you're looking for.

And when you select a folder, it is displayed at the bottom, though not as a traditional status bar.

Comment: Is there a short-cut to get the old menu bar back?

Comment: There's no shortcut because it's developed that way in Gnome. They want to move away from menu bars. It's a popular design these days that I don't necessarily agree with. I much prefer the way it's done in Ubuntu. But Nautilus is a Gnome project.